# Compile error- article to report

Tags: errors, compiling, article

The following is giving me a compile error - please help. 
(It does not give an error when I have the document type as a report instead of an article and accoringly chapter instead of section, section instead of subsection etc.)

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{images/}}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{vmargin}
    \setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb, gensymb}
    \usepackage{graphics,color}
    \usepackage{bm}

    \title{Rotating laser level - article}          % Title
    \author{G.V Bunge }             % Author
    \date{\today}                                           % Date

    \makeatletter
    \let\thetitle\@title
    \let\theauthor\@author
    \let\thedate\@date
    \makeatother

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\theauthor}
    \lhead{\thetitle}
    \cfoot{\thepage}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{0.5 cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.75]{UCT.jpg}\\[1.0 cm]   % University Logo
\textsc{\LARGE University of Cape Town}\\[2.0 cm]   % University Name
\textsc{\Large APG4003Z}\\[0.5 cm]              % Course Code
\textsc{\large Research Project}\\[0.5 cm]              % Course Name
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Author:}\\
        \theauthor
        \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Student Number:} \\
        BNGGER001                               % Your Student Number
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2 cm]

{\large \thedate}\\[2 cm]

\vfill

    \end{titlepage}

    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}

    \section*{Declaration of Authorship}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration of Authorship}

    \section*{Ethics Form}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ethics Form}

    \section*{Acknowledgements}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}

    \section*{Abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

    \section*{List of Terms}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Terms}

    \section*{List of Figures}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

    \section*{List of Tables}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

    \cleardoublepage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \section{Introduction}

    \subsection{Background to Research}

    \subsection{Objective of Research}

    \subsection{Research Question}

    \subsection{Research Methods}

    \subsection{Scope of Research}

    \section{Literature Review}
    \subsection{Instruments}
    \subsubsection{Precise Level}
    \subsubsection{Dumpy Level}
    \subsubsection{Theodolite}
    \subsubsection{Rotational Laser Level}
    \subsubsection{Stabila LAR 350 Rotational Laser Level}
    \subsection{Refraction}
    \subsubsection{Atmospheric Pressure}
    \subsubsection{Temperature}

    \subsection{Signals}
    \subsubsection{Infra-red Light}
    \subsubsection{Visible Light}

    \subsection{Experimental Method}

    \section{Theory}
    \subsection{Instruments}
    \subsubsection{Precise Level}
    \subsubsection{Dumpy Level}
    \subsubsection{Theodolite}
    \subsubsection{Rotational Laser Level}
    \subsubsection{Stabila LAR 350 Rotational Laser Level}
    \subsection{Refraction}
    \subsubsection{Atmospheric Pressure}
    \subsubsection{Temperature}

    \subsection{Signals}
    \subsubsection{Infra-red Light}
    \subsubsection{Visible Light}

    \subsection{Experimental Method}


    \section{Methodology of Research}
    \subsection{Instruments}
    \subsubsection{Precise Level}
    \subsubsection{Dumpy Level}
    \subsubsection{Theodolite}
    \subsubsection{Rotational Laser Level}
    \subsubsection{Stabila LAR 350 Rotational Laser Level}
    \subsection{Refraction}
    \subsubsection{Atmospheric Pressure}
    \subsubsection{Temperature}

    \subsection{Signals}
    \subsubsection{Infra-red Light}
    \subsubsection{Visible Light}

    \subsection{Experimental Method}


    \section{Results}


    \section{Analysis}


    \section{Conclusion}


    \cite{bibtex}

    \section{Appendices}


    \bibliographystyle{bibstyle}

    \bibliography{biblist}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: What error does it give?  It will greatly help everyone (yourself most of all) if you cut this down to a minimal example - the shortest file that you think should work but doesn't.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On my installation, in which I did not yet remove the TeXLive2016 installation, there is an error: `(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/support/pedigree-perl/examples/english.
cfg
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.1 #
      An example configuration file for pedigree program
? ` .

Comment: @marmot ??? what is it doing inputting files in the `/doc/` tree and what is inputtng `pedigree-perl` ??? I suppose I had better try tl2016....

Comment: correction on the second run you get `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I have no clue. This was just to tell you that I got an error other than the one you got.

Comment: ./main.toc:10: 
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. 

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.10 ...numberline 

{1.1}Background to Research}{1} @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @Gerald yes that's the error you get from the corrupt toc file, you need to delete that file and regenerate a good onewithout the chapter entries

Answer (score 4):

you are adding toc by hand for `\section*` but adding them for the `chapter` level which is not defined in `article`

```
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration of Authorship}
                          ^^^^^^^^
```

that needs to be `section`

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you.
I still have a compile error though.

Comment: @Gerald you would need to delete the corrupt aux and toc files after fixing your source. If you still have an error (you should not have) then (and in futire:-) show the full error message from the log file from `!` to `?` in a code block so line ends are preserved. Otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: okay, I clicked on recompile from scratch and it compiled fine.